# Cast from Python object back to struct

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have declared a struct for embedded Python via:

```cpp
struct Report {
    int Count;
};

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(embedded, m) {
    pybind11::class_<Report>(m, "Report")
        .def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("Count", &Report::Count);
}
```

I then call Python code which sets values on this struct and returns it:

```cpp
py::module_ m = py::module_::import("PythonTest");

// get a handle to function
py::object fn = m.attr("get_count");

py::object result = fn().cast<py::object>();

Report e = result.cast<Report>();
```

`PythonTest.py`:

```py
import embedded

def get_count():
    result = embedded.Result
    result.Count = 10
    return result
```

But the final cast in C++ fails with `Unable to cast Python instance to C++ type`.

This seems to be successful in cast:

```
Report r1;
r1.Count = 10;
py::object result = py::cast(r1);
Report r2 = result.cast<Report>();
```

How do I cast the `Report` class I declared for Python back to the original `Report` C++ struct?

Comment: If my Report struct ends up being a large nested object containing other srructs would I be better off serializing to a shared format like JSON, Protobuf, FlatBuffers etc?

Comment: Shouldn't you invoke the constructor of `Result` in that Python code? i.e. change the first line of the `get_count` function to `result = embedded.Result()`. Right now `result` is the class, not its instance.

Comment: Doh, you're right. Can't believe I missed that. I was previously returning result.Count as int and that worked, that's why I thought thr result object was fine.